# Alignment across table rows of divs with dynamic height (fluid layout) - CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment, fluid-layout

I'm working on a mobile site, which has a fluid layout. On the main page, I have a table which contains a few products.
Each product has 3 divs: `product-image`, `product-name` and `prices-container`.
I can't seem to figure out how to align the `prices-container` div horizontally across the table-rows.
I'm thinking that there would be 2 approaches to this problem: either `product-name` always takes the height of the highest `product-name` across the table-row, either `prices-container` always sticks to the bottom of my product table-cell. Can't seem to figure out how to apply any.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S12Ha.png)'s an illustration of the problem.
Left image shows my problem and right image shows how I would like it to be.

This wouldn't be a problem if `product-name` would have a fixed height, but due to the fact that this text is dynamic, I cannot know what height it will have. Might be one line of text, might be 10 lines.

I created a CodePen, where you can check my code and the problem >>[here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wguEn)<< (I know it looks ugly, using background-colors to figure out faster what's happening).
I'm using Jade for my HTML and Stylus for my CSS.

Limitations:
- must be CSS & HTML only, I would prefer not using Javascript
- solution must be suitable for fluid layout (width is set with percentage)
- cannot use a fixed height of `product-name`, this being a dynamic text

Any ideas how to do this? Thank you! :)

Comment: set a min-height or place your 4 buttons at `bottom : 0` ?

Comment: it's working perfect here on my PC. I am using Chrome.

Comment: @kevpoccs: Using `min-height` will only work in some cases. I need a general solution for whatever amount of text will be in that div. I also tried `bottom: 0` on the `bottom-container` and I don't see any change.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui: I'm guessing you have a very large screen and all the text in the `product-name` occupies 1 line. Try resizing the browser window to smaller and you'll see how they will become misaligned just like in the picture posted.

Answer (score 1):

add `vertical-align:bottom;` css style  to `.box1` class.
Similarly, add same style for `.box4` css class.
Thanks,

Comment: I tried what you suggested. It does indeed align the `bottom-container` across the table-rows, but it creates another problem. All the content in `.box1` and `.box4` is shifted to align at the bottom, meaning that also the `product-image` div will be shifted down, now causing misalignment between `product-image` across the table-rows. So I cannot use this solution. Moreover, I need something that will work no matter what amount of text will be in each `product-name`, not just in this specific case. (something to be added to all `.box` classes - related to your answer).